# Solving $ \lambda \int_{c_1/2}^{c_2/2} t^{\lambda-1}e^{-t}dt = \int_{c_1/2}^{c_2/2} t^{\lambda}e^{-t}dt$ for $c_1$, $c_2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, statistics

Following [my earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175721/solving-int-c-1c-2df-int-c-1c-2dg-for-c-1-c-2) question, using the formulas of chi-squared CDF's,

$$ F(x, k) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k/2)}\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2},\frac{x}{2}\right) $$

I've reduced the system of equations

$$\left\{  
 \begin{array}{rl}
F(c_2, 2\lambda) - F(c_1, 2\lambda) = 1 - \alpha \\
F(c_2, 2\lambda+2) - F(c_1, 2\lambda+2)  = 1 - \alpha 
 \end{array} \right.$$

where $\lambda > 0$ and $\alpha$ are known, to

$$ 
 \begin{array}{rl}
F(c_2, 2\lambda) - F(c_1, 2\lambda) &= F(c_2, 2\lambda+2) - F(c_1, 2\lambda+2) \\ 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\lambda)}( \Gamma\left(\lambda,\frac{c_2}{2}\right) - \Gamma\left(\lambda,\frac{c_1}{2}\right)) &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\lambda+1)}( \Gamma\left(\lambda+1,\frac{c_2}{2}\right) - \Gamma\left(\lambda+1,\frac{c_1}{2}\right)) \\  
 \Gamma\left(\lambda,\frac{c_2}{2}\right) - \Gamma\left(\lambda,\frac{c_1}{2}\right)&= \frac{1}{\lambda}( \Gamma\left(\lambda+1,\frac{c_2}{2}\right) - \Gamma\left(\lambda+1,\frac{c_1}{2}\right)) \\  
\int_{c_1/2}^{c_2/2} t^{\lambda-1}e^{-t}dt &= \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{c_1/2}^{c_2/2} t^{\lambda}e^{-t}dt
 \end{array} $$

> If I didn't mess anything up, the goal here is to solve
>
> $$ \lambda \int_{c_1/2}^{c_2/2} t^{\lambda-1}e^{-t}dt = \int_{c_1/2}^{c_2/2} t^{\lambda}e^{-t}dt$$

which, if we denote $A(\lambda) = \int_{c_1/2}^{c_2/2} t^{\lambda}e^{-t}dt$, would seem to look like solving

$$ A(\lambda) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} A(\lambda) $$

for some $c_1$ and $c_2$.

However, I'm not sure how to proceed or how to tackle this further, so any advices or solutions would really be appreciated!

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dt}(e^{-t}t^\lambda) = \lambda t^{\lambda-1}e^{-t} - t^{\lambda}e^{-t}$. Integrate this!

Comment: @Winther very nice, I'll look into it asap, thanks!

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to $c_2^{2\lambda}e^{c_1}=c_1^{2\lambda}e^{c_2}$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire yes, seems about right. I suppose there is no further simplification, apart from fixing one parameter, and writing the other through Lambert's W? If so, I think I can close this question, thank you both!